# How to crop canvas image by path, not area

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Im making a painting tool, and one of the feature is showing cropped image of the drawn path.

[The path I have drawn(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JHP1.png)

For example in above the picture, the white colored path indicates what I have drawn, just like a painting tool.

[Cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Invq8.png)

And here is the cropped image of the path. If you look at the picture, you can see that it crops the image as if the path is closed and therefore it crops the image "area" not the path.

and here is the code

```
function crop({ image, points }) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const { width, height } = getImageSize(image);
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    context.beginPath();
    points.forEach(([x, y], idx) => {
      if (idx === 0) {
        context.moveTo(x, y);
      } else {
        context.lineTo(x, y);
      }
    });
    context.clip();

    context.drawImage(image);

    ...etc
}
```

The `crop` function receives `points` which is consisted [x coordinate, y coordinate][ ] of the drawn path.

Is there an way to show image only the path that I've painted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more what is generally called a mask then, but note that both for the current clip or for the mask you want to attain, the best is to use compositing.

Canvas context has various [compositing options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), allowing you to generate complex compositions, from pixels's alpha value.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pathes = [[]];
let down = false;
let dirty = false;
const bg = new Image();
bg.onload = begin;
bg.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Serene_Sunset_%2826908986301%29.jpg/320px-Serene_Sunset_%2826908986301%29.jpg';

function begin() {
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);
  addEventListener('mousedown', onmousedown);
  addEventListener('mouseup', onmouseup);
  anim();
  ctx.fillText("Use your mouse to draw a path", 20,50) 
}

function anim() {
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  if(dirty) draw();
  dirty = false;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  pathes.forEach(path => {
    if(!path.length) return;
    ctx.moveTo(path[0].x, path[0].y);
    path.forEach(pt => {
      ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
    });
  });
  // old drawings will remain on where new drawings will be
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.stroke();
  // reset
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}

function onmousemove(evt) {
  if(!down) return;
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pathes[pathes.length - 1].push({
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  });
  dirty = true;
}
function onmousedown(evt) {
  down = true;
}
function onmouseup(evt) {
  down = false;
  pathes.push([]);
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Don't hesitate to look at all the compositing options, various cases will require different options, for instance if you need to draw multiple paths, you may prefer to render first your paths and then keep your image only where you did already drawn, using the `source-atop` option:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pathes = [[]];
pathes[0].lineWidth = (Math.random() * 20) + 0.2;
let down = false;
let dirty = false;
const bg = new Image();
bg.onload = begin;
bg.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Serene_Sunset_%2826908986301%29.jpg/320px-Serene_Sunset_%2826908986301%29.jpg';

function begin() {
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);
  addEventListener('mousedown', onmousedown);
  addEventListener('mouseup', onmouseup);
  anim();
  ctx.fillText("Use your mouse to draw a path", 20,50) 
}

function anim() {
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  if(dirty) draw();
  dirty = false;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  pathes.forEach(path => {
    if(!path.length) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = path.lineWidth;
    ctx.moveTo(path[0].x, path[0].y);
    path.forEach(pt => {
      ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
    });
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  // new drawings will appear on where old drawings were
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  
  // reset
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}

function onmousemove(evt) {
  if(!down) return;
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pathes[pathes.length - 1].push({
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  });
  dirty = true;
}
function onmousedown(evt) {
  down = true;
}
function onmouseup(evt) {
  down = false;
  const path = [];
  path.lineWidth = (Math.random() * 18) + 2;
  pathes.push(path);
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And also remember that you can very well have canvases that you won't append to the document that you can use as layers to generate really complex compositions. (`drawImage()` does accept a <canvas> as source).

Comment: Your answer helped me alot. Im one step far away from what I want to implement. One last question, is there a way to create multiple 'destination-in' drawings? I painted 3 separated paintings that has different lineWidth(which is not connected therefor 3 separated context.beginPath is executed) but nothing gets left because well, 'destination-in' keeps canvas content where the new shape and exisiting content overlaps and since Im generating "3 'new' and 'separated'" shapes each time, they are being drawn after each content processed content.

Comment: If they all share the same background, then do it the other way around, using `source-atop`: draw your pathes in source-over, and then draw the image only where you already drawn, by using source-atop. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you are my hero everything worked after doing what u told me :) thx alot

Comment: can I ask you a quick, related question about Canvas and SVG? What are the possible ways to draw a paint of an object on the SVG that is received by image type. For example, I got a picture of plain black doughnut shaped object on white background. I draw that image on canvas and get all the pixel coordinates that its color is #000000. And with that coordinates I draw a Polyline on SVG. are there any better ways to achieve this? I would defo like to hear your opinion.

Comment: @ChanwooPark I am sorry, I'm not sure to understand clearly your case. Could you set up a jsfiddle with what you have? And maybe it's even worth it's own question?

Comment: I think it will be better to create its own question :) I'll let you know when i make one I'll come back in a minute

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644628/how-to-draw-polyline-object-shaped-exactly-same-with-the-given-image-data-on-svg) this is the link to a new question. It would be such a big help getting opinion from you