# How to draw Polyline object shaped exactly same with the given image data on SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

[Doughnut picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHqm3.png)

For example, given image like above, what I want to do is draw the exact same shaped polyline object on SVG(Im creating a 'drawing' or should I say 'brush' tool based on SVG and that is why Im using polyline so that user can paint with his mouse or can even use eraser with his or hers mouse). And following is how I would achieve this.

1. draw the given image on canvas context.
2. get all the coordinates of pixel that is colored #000000.
3. with that list of coordinates create a Polyline on SVG.

and by this process I get this as a result [doughnut drawin with svg polyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeR0J.png)(now this is just an example result that it is formed ugly because I had to draw it manually with my hand. But my purpose is to get same shaped with an input image)

But I'm not sure if this is the only way or even not sure if I should stick with SVG. Are there any other good ways to achieve this? or would using canvas instead of SVG make it easier?

Answer (score 2):

This shape can be drawn with circles.
Cutouts made using a mask composed of circles

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="405" height="401" viewBox="0 0 405 401" >  
<defs>
<mask id="msk1" >
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
<g fill="black">
 <circle cx="202" cy="200" r="40"   />
 <circle cx="260" cy="298" r="40"   />
 <circle cx="215" cy="303" r="20"   />
</g>
</mask>
</defs> 
<circle cx="202" cy="200" r="98"  fill="black" mask="url(#msk1)" />
```

Comment: The main purpose of this question is to generate a SVG object that is 'exactly' same with the given image data but not how to draw a doughnut. Meaning, the coordinate of the pixel that is black should be preserved.  My apology if my question mislead you. The shape doughnut itself does not matter in this situation. Any given shapes like car or flower or etc object might be an input data.

Comment: @ChanwooPark Then you probably need to look for programs that can convert raster images to svg using the command line

Answer (score 1):

This is supposing that you already have an SVG path.

In order to draw a polygon you will need to split your path by the `M` commands. In the next example I did it manually but you can do it dynamically. This is important because otherwise you'll get a split in the polygon.

You will also need to set a precision, meaning the distance between the points of the polygon.

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll("#theGroup path");
let precision = 5;//how far one of other the points of the polygon are
let points = [];// the array of points

// for each path in the array of paths 
paths.forEach(p=>{
  // get the total length
  let totalLength = p.getTotalLength();
  // get the number of points for the polygon in base of the precision
  let numPoints = ~~(totalLength / precision);
  // calculate the segment length
  let segmentLength = totalLength / numPoints;
 
  for(let i = 0; i <= numPoints; i++ ){
  let point = p.getPointAtLength(i*segmentLength);
  // get the coordinates of this point and push it
  points.push(point.x);
  points.push(point.y);
}
})

//set the value for the points attribute of the polygon
poly.setAttributeNS(null,"points", points.join())
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh;}
path{fill:none}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 531 531">
<g id="theGroup">
 <path id="donut" d="M268.64,76.066c70.065,2.632,125.154,32.347,163.73,91.372
  c14.944,22.864,23.47,48.161,27.698,75.22c3.987,25.512,2.188,50.551-3.64,75.354c-4.821,20.522-13.383,39.648-24.866,57.406
  c-2.003,3.099-3.899,3.396-7.365,1.548c-30.011-16.005-64.509-10.767-87.731,14.13c-6.295,6.748-9.985,15.893-15.108,23.783
  c-1.548,2.384-3.508,5.256-5.938,6.189c-19.202,7.375-32.874,20.547-41.279,39.064c-1.911,4.211-4.254,5.562-8.308,5.085
  c-13.198-1.554-26.507-2.515-39.562-4.873c-30.46-5.502-57.275-19.262-81.055-38.724c-28.703-23.491-49.496-52.646-61.424-88.046
  c-7.479-22.198-11.34-44.892-10.42-68.225c2.042-51.761,20.944-96.305,57.854-133.023c22.272-22.156,48.427-37.859,78.3-47.183
  C228.671,79.17,248.365,75.884,268.64,76.066z"/> 
                      
<path id="hole" d="M340.466,271.259c0.179-40.212-32.175-73.14-72.067-73.348
  c-40.072-0.208-73.264,32.326-73.485,72.032c-0.226,40.441,32.218,73.372,72.436,73.522
  C307.646,343.616,340.286,311.382,340.466,271.259z"/>
</g>
  
  <polygon id="poly" fill="gold" points = "" />
</svg>
```